# File contents lost after power outage

Tags: linux, stream

I am using C++ ofstream to write a log file on Linux. When I monitor the file contents with tail -f command I can see the contents are correctly populated. But if a power outage happens and I check the file again after power cycle, the last couple lines of records are gone. With hexdump I can see those records turned into null characters '\0' instead. I tried flush() and manipulator std::endl and they don't help anyway.

Is it true what tail showed to me was not actually written to the disk and they were just in buffer? The inode table wasn't update before the power outage? I can accept this fact but I don't understand why the records turned to null characters if they weren't written to the file.

Btw, I tried Google's glog and have the same results (a bunch of null characters at the end). I also tried zlog, a C library. and found it only lost the last records but didn't replace them with null chars.

Comment: use sync instead of flush. Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251873/what-is-the-difference-between-flush-and-sync-in-regard-to-fstream-buffers

Comment: Purely hypothetical explanation: `tail` is showing the contents of the operating system's cache or the disk controller's buffer. The file has been expanded (with zeros), the contents have (probably) been written to the disk controller's buffer, but the controller hasn't written its buffer to disk yet.

Comment: @molbdnilo I think you are suggesting the file system updated immediately to reflect the new size of the file but the data never had a chance to be written into disk by the disk controller. Then who decides to actually write the data, OS?disk controller firmware?

Comment: @Donghui I understand sync can do better than flush but it comes with cost for logging. I guess that's why not every logging library, e.g. glog, is using this way if it prefers performance than consistency.

Comment: yeah it's a tradeoff

Comment: @DonghuiZhang, use `sync(2)` **in addition to `flush()`** or you'll get all the written data to disk, but not the one held in the output buffer of `ostream`.

Comment: @molbdnilo, today, almost all systems use ordered data write, and that means first write data on disk, before you point to it, preventing pointers pointing to data not already written, so there's no chance (at least in linux or BSD systems) to get what you say in your comment.  The problem here is that data is on kernel system buffers, but not actually written to disk.  Just forcing write with fsync(2) system cal or sync(2) will force them to be written before continuing.... but beware of making too many sync(2) calls as it affects efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you have a power outage, and then start the system again, the linux kernel tries to forward the journal log to detect and correct the inconsistencies held from memory to disk when the system crashed.  Normally this means to redo and commit all operations possible until the system crash, but undo (and erase) all data not commited on the time of the crash.

Linux (and other un*x kernels, like freebsd) has a facility called ordered data write, that forces metadata (like block pointers from inodes, or directory entries) to be updated **after** the actual data they point to is effectively written on disk, so inconsistencies reduce to a minimum.  I don't know the actual linux implementation, but for example, in freebsd what you point (a block of zeros in a file instead of the actual data written) is completely impossible with freebsd kernel (well, you can do it on purpose, but not accidentally)  The most probable thing is that linux probably just manages the blocks info and not the file contents, or it has updated the file size pointer and not the data up to there.  This should not happen as it's an already solved problem.

The other thing is how many data you have written or why what you see on the screen doesn't appear after the system crash.  Probably you have heard about something called *delayed write* that allows the kernel to save write operations to disk on busy systems by not writing immediately data onto disk, but waiting some time so updates can be resolved in core memory buffers before they go to disk.  Disk writes, anyway, are forced after some time delay, that means 5secs in linux (I try to remember, there's a lot of time I checked that value last time, I'm in doubt between 5 and 30 seconds) so you can lose your last five seconds at most.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will experiment on freebsd. Yes my file system is EXT4 ordered data mode. My understanding was like you explained that the metadata is updated after the actual data is written. But the result seems opposite. What troubles me is the log parser has to deal with such exception even they are just a block zeros).

Comment: That indeed should be incorrect, as if you repair the filesystem, you have a corrupted file, which cannot be good.  If you open after the repair the fille and append to it, it will show a block of zero bytes which is not a good thing.